# How to translate element position from x1 to x2 using transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #f00; }
.a { -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear; -webkit-transform: translateY(100px); }
.b { -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var elm = $('#foo');

    var animate = function (className, callback) {
        elm.addClass(className);

        setTimeout(function () {
            elm.removeClass(className)

            callback();
        }, 1000);
    };

    animate('a', function () {
        animate('b');
    });
});
```

PROBLEM:

During the second iteration the element is actually moved from the previously translatedY, rather than the translate-less element state.

Using keyframes would work, though that would require adding a lot more predefined CSS classes, which isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution that I came up with is using `setTimeout`.

```
$(function () {
    var elm = $('#foo');

    var animate = function (className, callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            elm.addClass(className);
        }, 0);

        setTimeout(function () {
            elm.removeClass(className)

            callback();
        }, 1000);
    };

    animate('a', function () {
        animate('b');
    });
});
```

Deme of the two can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/CP8An/ and http://jsfiddle.net/CP8An/1/. The latter is the desired result.

I don't understand why `setTimeout` is needed – after all, the previously defined class is removed before calling the callback. Using `setTimeout` seem to be more like a workaround than a solution. This might help to someone who is dealing with a similar issue, though I am nevertheless open to alternative suggestions.